# Changing bulb in shower ceiling light fixture

Tags: bathroom

I have a light fixture in the ceiling of my shower.  (see pic)  It has a cage over the glass dome, which I was able to remove so okay there.

Problem now is that I cannot seem to get the glass dome to turn either way so I can take it off and put in a new light bulb.  I have tried pulling down, no luck.  I tried turning the glass dome counter-clockwise as it seems logical, but the whole fixture spins in the ceiling.  I am worried I will mess up the wiring if the whole fixture keeps turning.

Has anyone changed a bulb in one of these fixtures?  Can you help me out?[image]

Comment: I would suggest that you provide readers with photo that is zoomed in more with clear focus.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the whole fixture is spinning? The type of light rated for wet locations used to have a rubber seal and screw fittings. Most of the time the "jelly jar" type fixtures the glass needed to be unscrewed (and they do get stuck and feel like they are going to break). There were some the metal ring was threaded holding the glass in place. So it could be that you need to unscrew the ring. Also check the ring for a small set screw to lock the Glass / ring in place.